# First Port of entry for German National visa holders

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, europe, international-travel, long-stay-visas

I will be travelling to MUC from India on a German national visa type D via Paris. My visa says that it is valid for Deutschland (not Schengen states, unlike for Schengen Visa). Will I be allowed to travel through Paris as my first port of entry?

I am concerned since I will have to do immigration at Paris.

Comment: I am concerned about doing immigration in France with a visa valid for Germany.

Comment: If you look at the linked duplicate, you'll see that there's no reason for concern.  Despite being "for" Germany, a type-D visa is valid in the entire Schengen area for short stays, which includes transit.  The visa labeling is confusing, but the law is explicit on this matter.